# How do I create 3 column polygon container with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve a 3 column polygon grid with CSS and was wondering what the best approach would be. Currently I have taken the display grid approach as this codepen here will show you:

```css
.new{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: #0D0D0E;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
}
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-gap: 50px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.section1 { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: c;
    height: 840px;
    clip-path: polygon(0 28%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 175px;
}  
.section2 { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: d;
    height: 540px;
    clip-path: polygon(0 30%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    width: 100%;
}
.section3 { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: d;
    height: 340px;
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 19%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <section class="new">
    <div class="zindex-2 grid-container">
        <div>
            <div class="section1" style="background-color: skyblue;">
                section 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="section2" style="background-color: olive;">
                section 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="section3" style="background-color: tomato;">
                section 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

https://codepen.io/provole/pen/bGgLXeg

Design image:

[image: Design image]

Also I'd like to ideally have a second polygon within the second and third column.
What would the best approach be and is there a way to achieve this without having to repeat myself for every single shape?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of using grid to set out the 3 columns seems to work fine. And just adding another shape to any of the columns can be done by inserting another div as required.

To be able to reuse shapes, or introduce new ones, it might be better to separate out the concept of 'section' from 'shape'. Also as there is quite a bit of repetition in the CSS we can use CSS variables to define any particular shape plus color plus height. This makes the shapes  reusable and we can cut down on the repetition.

The following snippet gives this result just as a test:
[image]

```css
.new{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: #0D0D0E;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
}
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    grid-gap: 50px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

[class^="shape"] {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--h);
    clip-path: var(--path);
    --top: 0;
    margin-top: var(--top);
    background-color: var(--bg);
}
.shapea {
   --path: polygon(0 28%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 80%);
}  
.shapeb {
  --path: polygon(0 30%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
.shapec {
    --path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 19%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<section class="new">
    <div class="zindex-2 grid-container">
        <div>
            <div class="shapea" style="--bg: skyblue; --h: 840px; --top: 175px;">
                section 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="shapeb" style="--bg: olive;--h: 540px;">
                section 2.1
            </div>
            <div class="shapec" style="--bg: lime; --h: 240px;">
                section 2.2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="shapec" style="--bg: tomato; --h: 340px;">
                section 3.1
            </div>
            <div class="shapea" style="--bg: magenta; --h: 200px;">
                section 3.2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```